# get locale resource in bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, resources, locale, bootstrapping

I see lots of examples of people doing marvellous things starting with:

```
$locale = $this->getResource('locale');
```

in their bootstrap. But though I have

```
resources.locale.default = "nl_NL"
resources.locale.force = true
```

in my application.ini and

```
protected function _initLocale()
{
    $locale = $this->getResource('locale');
    // more code
}
```

var_dump($locale) still returns NULL and the locale applied elsewhere in my application is the zend default of "en(_US)".

What should I do to access (or initialise) the application wide locale set in my application.ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your Bootstrap method overrides the built-in application resource because it has the same name (the part after `_init`).

Try this instead

```
protected function _initLocaleMods()
{
    // always bootstrap required resources
    $this->bootstrap('locale');

    $locale = $this->getResource('locale');

    // more code
}
```

Comment: Thx Phil, this works! Though the bootstrap('locale') is indeed necessary here: why should I always bootstrap resources? I do not do this for view, db, mail etc and my application.ini settings still are getting picked up elsewhere.

Comment: @zensys The order of app resource and bootstrap method is not guaranteed so you should always ensure resources that your code depends on are ready for use. You would only bootstrap view, db, etc if your method or custom resource plugin depended on them. Read [Dependency Tracking](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap.dependency-tracking)